# ForEach-Object's syntax in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, syntax

I have a working Powershell statement like below,

```
$Uptime = $Uptime |  ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -eq "N/A"){return $_}else{'{0}:{1}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}' -f ($_.Duration()).Days,($_.Duration()).Hours,($_.Duration()).Minutes,($_.Duration()).Seconds}
}
```

Where `$Uptime` is an array of `DateTime` objects.

I like the one liner for my `else` statement, but I'd like to create a variable which contain `$_.Duration()` in my else statement instead of repeating it.

I tried,

```
$Uptime = $Uptime |  ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -eq "N/A"){return $_}else{ $d = $_.Duration() return '{0}:{1}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}' -f ($d).Days,($d).Hours,($d).Minutes,($d).Seconds}
}
```

Which obviously is not valid syntax (*unexpected token 'return'* in expression or statement).

Obviously my goal is to have the same behavior as above and return the formatted string `'{0}:{1}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}'`, but I can't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a semi-colon to enter multiple commands on the same line:

```
$d = $_.Duration(); return (<expression>) }
```

---

You don't need `return` because anything returned by the expressions will be sent to the output stream, which is being assigned to your variable `$Uptime`.

```
$Uptime = $Uptime |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq "N/A") {
            $_
        } else {
            $d = $_.Duration()
            '{0}:{1}:{2:D2}:{3:D2}' -f $d.Days,$d.Hours,$d.Minutes,$d.Seconds
        }
    }
```

This is equivalent to what you wrote.

---

You can further shorten your formatting string (assuming `$d` is a `DateTime` object):

```
'{0:dd}:{0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}' -f $d
```

or even

```
$_.Duration() | Get-Date -UFormat %d:%H:%M:%S
```